# Generate HMAC Sha256 in python 3

Tags: python, rest, api, webhooks, hmac

I write code to verify an HMAC Auth incoming POST request with JSON to our API. The HMAC I received is `OD5ZxL4tdGgWr78e9vO3cYrjuOFT8WOrTbTIuuIH1PQ=`

When I try to generate it by my self using Python, it is always different.

Here is the JSON request I received:

```
{
    "shipper_id": 4841,
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "shipper_ref_no": "",
    "tracking_ref_no": "",
    "shipper_order_ref_no": "",
    "timestamp": "2018-05-23T15:13:28+0800",
    "id": "61185ecf-3484-4985-b625-ffe30ba36e28",
    "previous_status": "Pending Pickup",
    "tracking_id": "NVSGBHINK000000001"
}
```

And the client secret is `817a3723917f4c7fac24b1f1b324bbab`.

The HMAC secret I received is `OD5ZxL4tdGgWr78e9vO3cYrjuOFT8WOrTbTIuuIH1PQ=`.

Here is the code when I write it in PHP:

```
<?php
define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'my_shared_secret');
function verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header){
    $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, CLIENT_SECRET, true));
    return ($hmac_header == $calculated_hmac);
}  
$hmac_header = $_SERVER['X-NINJAVAN-HMAC-SHA256'];
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');  
$verified = verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header);
error_log('Webhook verified: '.var_export($verified, true)); //check error.log to see result
?>
```

But I have no idea how to do it in Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3 you basically want something like the following, taken from how you handle GitHub webhook requests.

```
import hashlib
import hmac

secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET'
data = rsp.content # assumes you're using requests for data/sig
signature = rsp.headers['X-Something-Signature']
signature_computed = 'sha1=' + hmac.new(
    key=secret.encode('utf-8'),
    msg=data.encode('utf-8'),
    digestmod=hashlib.sha1
).hexdigest()
if not hmac.compare_digest(signature, signature_computed):
    log("Invalid payload")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recreate the hashing code from PHP to Python do it thusly:

```
def create_signature(key, data):
    sig_hash =  hmac.new(key.encode('utf8'), data.encode('utf8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    base64_message = base64.b64encode(sig_hash).decode()
    return base64_message
```

This will create the signature that should match what your PHP code is creating.  Just compare the signature to what is sent in the header.

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

params = orderedDict()

params["shipper_id"] = 4841
params["status"] = "Cancelled"
params["shipper_ref_no"] = ""
params["tracking_ref_no"] = ""
params["shipper_order_ref_no"] = ""
params["timestamp"] = "2018-05-23T15:13:28+0800"
params["id"] = "61185ecf-3484-4985-b625-ffe30ba36e28"
params["previous_status"] = "Pending Pickup"
params["tracking_id"] = "NVSGBHINK000000001"
mes = json(params, separator = (";",",")).highdigest()
sighnature = hmac.new(mes, sha256)
# separators = (";",",") - i'm not shure
params['sighnature'] = sighnature
r = response.post(url,params,sighnature)
print(r.text())
```